# How to get deal BCC email using Pipedrive API?

Tags: pipedrive-api

On Sep 22, 2015 **Pipedrive** has introduced changes to smar BCC emails, including that each deal now has it's own BCC email.

For instance, main universal BCC email can me **mycompany@pipedrivemail.com**, and specific deal's BCC email - **mycompany+dealXXXX@pipedrivemail.com**.

It is not guaranteed, however, that this email's format can be auto-constructed from account name and deal id.

I thought it would be possible to get this deal-specific address by simply querying deal (ex. 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/XXX?api_token=My_TOKEN'), but deal's BCC email is not in the result.

I'm wondering if anyone has already faced this issue and has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hinting that you have the ID of the deal hence your line with 
https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/XXX

The XXX there is the ID of the deal.
The bcc address follows the same principle:
mycompany+dealXXX@pipedrivemail.com (XXX being the ID of the Deal)

So you dont really need to ask the API for the email address, you just need the ID of the deal.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm currently doing. My original question though was because this feature is not documented and hence not guaranteed to work in all cases (while I wanted to know 100% official way)